# How to load a plugin on a specific page in nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, openlayers, nuxt3, vue3-openlayers

I have an app with a map on only one page, built with [vue3-openlayers](https://github.com/MelihAltintas/vue3-openlayers).

Unfortunately, the package is big and ruin the performance of my whole app in the other pages.
I would like to load that plugin only when i'm on the /map page. I've tried to load the plugin only on page:start hook, on the component, on the page but nothing works and I  get `plugin already loaded` when I return to the page.

Here is my simplified code where the plugin is loaded gloabally:

```
 // vue3-openlayers.client
 export default defineNuxtPlugin({
  parallel: true,
  async setup(nuxtApp) {
      //let openLayersLoaded = false;
      //nuxtApp.hook('page:start', () => {
          //const route = useRoute()
          //if (route.fullPath === '/map' && !openLayersLoaded) {
            nuxtApp.vueApp.use(OpenLayers);
          //}
      //})
  }
 })
```

.

```
  // map.vue
  <template>
    <MyMap />
  </template
```

.

```
// myMap.vue
  // ...
  <ol-map
    :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true"
    :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true"
  >
    <ol-view
      ref="view"
      :center="center"
      :rotation="rotation"
      :zoom="zoom"
    />
    //...
  </ol-map>
```

Comment: Why not load the package locally in the `.vue` file, in the script section then (or a composable)? Since a plugin is indeed meant to be something global for the app. This way you scope down the thing to that specific part of your app.

Comment: I tried to add
`const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
nuxtApp.vueApp.use(OpenLayers);` in myMap.vue
it's working when I navigate from an another page to /map but when I'm reloading the page on /map
I get:
`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'node_modules/ol/Feature' imported from node_modules/vue3-openlayers/dist/vue3-openlayers.es.js`

Comment: Can't you use `OpenLayersMap` (the object) itself? The error is mainly an SSR-issue, make a conditional to only load it on the client. Some other issues are available on the [repo itself](https://github.com/MelihAltintas/vue3-openlayers/issues?q=is%3Aissue+nuxt).